# Provable/Oraclalize: How to get msg.sender in __callback

Tags: oracles

How do I get the `msg.sender` of the user who called `randomNumber()` in the `__callback`?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.4.25.sol";

contract ExampleContract is usingProvable {
 function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
  if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
  // how do i get the address of the user who called "randomNumber"?
 }

 function randomNumber() public {
  provable_query("WolframAlpha", "random number between 0 and 100");
 }
}
```

documentation: https://docs.provable.xyz/#ethereum-quick-start

Answer (score 1):

You can to implement your own solution. For example using a mapping to link queryId and message's sender.

```
mapping (bytes32 => address) requests;

function randomNumber() public {
    bytes32 queryId = provable_query("WolframAlpha", "random number between 0 and 100");
    requests[queryId] = msg.sender;
}
```

You know who send the query using the mapping

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
    if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
    address sender = requests[myid];
}
```